# regex swapping commented HTML in and out

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm having a bit of trouble with a couple of regex's that I almost got working earlier. I basically need to remove HTML comments from either side of a specific `<span>` tag.

This is what I have so far:

```
.replace(/<!--<span aria-hidden=\"true\" data-icon=\"e\"/,
         '<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="e"')

.replace(/onclick=\"deletetodo(this)\"><\/span>-->/, 
         'onclick="deletetodo(this)"></span>');
```

Maybe I've been staring at this for too long and I can't spot an obvious mistake, but if anyone knows why this wont get rid of the `<!--` and `-->` tags, you'd be saving me a massive headache!

Thanks.

[edit] Multi-lined for SO only, in code they're on a single line. [/edit]

Comment: Maybe there is more whitespace in the original string? HTML tends to be like that.

Comment: try wrapping pattern strings in single quotes instead of `/ /`

Comment: How are you using that, for what do you need it? Seems you are [misusing regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses should be escaped in regex when they are part of the string; you should try:

```
.replace(/onclick=\"deletetodo\(this\)\"><\/span>-->/, ...
```

instead of

```
.replace(/onclick=\"deletetodo(this)\"><\/span>-->/, ...
```

Comment: Doing this, plus the suggested: swap `\"` with just `'` worked like a charm!